# PostgreSQL - WHERE clause not working - Column name not found

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-literals

My simple WHERE query is not working. It says column "Exception" does not exist, but the column it type, that is only a value.

SQL Query:

```
select * from logs
where type = "Exception"
```

[image: Picture of the error]

Comment: `"` characters are for column names. You have to use `'` characters.

Comment: @S-Man More generally, double quotes are for _identifiers_, which could include table and database names, in addition to column names.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: @LukaszDabrowski: you will need double quotes for your case sensitive column names however. You should really re-create that table **without** using any double quotes. As a rule of thumb: never use double quotes in SQL

Answer (score 4):

As S-Man commented the answer is:
`"` characters are for column names. You have to use `'` characters.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   logs
WHERE
   type = 'Exception'
```